# KeyEvent is triggering 2 events - can I add a delay?

Tags: java, android, authentication, focus

So I have the following code for a username and password field.  I would like to have the Enter key in Android move the cursor to the Password field.  This is working, however, my code also triggers the password field to call the signUpOrLogin function.

Is there a way to add a delay or a way to get around this?

```
if (usernameField.hasFocus() && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
  passwordField.requestFocus();
  }

if (passwordField.hasFocus() && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
  signUpOrLogin(v);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an `isEmpty()` to the if statement to check that the `TextField` has been used. This will make it so that the field has to have a value for the statement to execute. Your code would look like the following:
(Note that I haven't tested this)

```
    if (!usernameField.getText().isEmpty() && usernameField.hasFocus() && KeyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
         passwordField.requestFocus();
    }

    if (!passwordField.getText().isEmpty() && passwordField.hasFocus() && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
         signUpOrLogin(v);
    }
```

Hope this helps. :)